# How to do multi-statements in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongodb/mongoose in My Node/Express.js project.

But I don't how to ensure data integrity. Seems mongodb has no `commit` like MySql.

For example:

```
Comments = new Schema({
    data: String,
    author: String,
    post: String,
  })

  Posts = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    comments: [String]
  })
```

How to insert a comment to post?

```
Posts.findOne({id: _id}, function(err, post) { 
  Comments.insert({title: 123, body: 123}, function(err, comment) { 
    post.comments.push(comment._id);
    post.save(function(err, result) { 
      if(err) { return console.log(err); } 
      res.json({ok: 'Comment OK!'})
    })
  })
})
```

if post.save fails, there will be dirty comment in Comment

I searched a lot, don't have a clear view of how mongodb handles this

Comment: If post.save fails delete also the comment and show an error as response

Comment: BTW read something here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support transactions like most of RDBS do.